# database optimization: to use WordPress' built in tables or add my own?

Tags: mysql, database, wordpress

I'm building a part onto a WP site that is similar to a "bidding" board. Basically it will have items with price, time, expiration, etc.  Not too many fields.

Before I begin, I'm curious about the pros and cons of building these bid "items" as custom post types, allowing them to be viewable through the WP backend - but then they are all in the `wp_posts` table, meaning they are mixed with everything else.

Is there a big speed hit on this?  In other words, should I create another `wp_bids` table and store ONLY bids in there?  The con to this would be that the end user wouldn't have a built in way to see this through the backend (I'd have to build that system) and would take me a long time... Can someone offer some insight on this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is going to be a performance difference. Doing it through WordPress' tables and interface will most likely be slower. How much slower depends on many things, and how slow it's allowed to be is only something you can decide. You may never notice the difference.

The only ways to find out would be to do it both ways and compare, or make some representative examples and see how they perform.